# g++ warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning

To compile my C++ code I use the `-W` flag, which causes the warning:

> warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false

I believe this was considered as a bug and was fixed on version GCC 4.3, but I'm using GCC 4.1

Code that is obviously offending here:

```
void FieldGroup::generateCreateMessage (const ApiEvent::GroupData &data, omsgstream &result) const {
  dblog << debug;

  // Write out the data fields we care about, in the order they were specified
  for (size_t index = 0; index < fields.size(); ++index) {
    size_t esIndex = clsToES[index];
    if (esIndex < 0 || esIndex >= data.fields.length()) {
      ostringstream buf;
      buf << "Invalid field " << index << " (index in ES data set " << esIndex << ", " << data.fields.length() << " fields returned)";
      throw InvalidDataException (buf.str());
    }
    fields[index].writeData (data.fields[esIndex], result);
  }
}
```

Warning I'm getting:

> dbtempl.cpp: In member function ‘void ECONZ::FieldGroup::generateCreateMessage(const nz::co::econz::eventServer::ApiEvent::GroupData&, ECONZ::omsgstream&) const’:
>   dbtempl.cpp:480: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false

How can i possibly stop these warnings from appearing? I don't want to remove the `-W` flag.

Comment: Just a small remark: compilers can have bugs, but those are really rare. So when the compilation produces warnings, check your code **first** and don't assume it's a bug from the compiler.

Comment: my bad. i kind of misread the gnu bug report found here: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23587

Comment: Interesting: GCC 4.5.1 does not complain if you compare an unsigned quantity with '< 0' in either the GCC or G++ compilers, even when prodded with '-Wall'.  It requires '-Wextra' to generate the warning now.  Maybe you should upgrade from GCC 4.1 to GCC 4.3 or later?

Comment: Indeed. The bug is that the warning wasn't always raised ;)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: I never understood why warnings are disabled by default.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are testing if a positive value is below 0.

A `size_t` is unsigned, so at least 0.

This can **never** happen and the compiler optimize things out by just removing the test. The warning is here to tell you because if someone does that, it might be a mistake.

In your case, you might just remove the test, it should be fine.

Comment: Just a comment because it happend to me: if you subtract to unsigned int, e.g. `unsigned int a=3` and `unsigned int b=4`, then `a-b<0` will always be false due to overflow.

Answer (score 6):

`size_t` is an unsigned integral type. Hence, the compiler sees that the comparison `< 0` will always be false (the Standard does specify 2's complement wrapping when overflow occurs). You should take that comparison out as it is a no-op (and the compiler will probably not generate any code for it).

> Unsigned integers, declared unsigned, shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2n where n is the number
>   of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer.<sup>46</sup>

and the corresponding footnote:

> 46) This implies that unsigned
>   arithmetic does not overflow because a
>   result that cannot be represented by
>   the resulting unsigned integer type is
>   reduced modulo the number that is one
>   greater than the largest value that
>   can be represented by the resulting
>   unsigned integer type.

Answer (score 3):

Renove the characters `esIndex < 0 ||`

This part of code is totally meaningless to the machine, which is why the compiler warns you - "did you mean to do something else?".

Answer (score -1):

> How can i possibly stop these warnings from appearing ? I don't want to remove -W flag.

:|

Just correct your code and the warning will disappear ... that's the idea ...

The warnings are there to help you produce correct, cleaner, more efficient code.

Comment: How about the case where reusable code is drawing a *const* size_t value from a client-customised header file? In some cases, the const value might be set to zero (say, number of audio channels), and the intention is that these loops simply drop out of compilation if zero. Would be nice to write it in a way that didn't produce a compiler warning. One could use preprocessor macros instead I suppose...

Comment: By defining a `static const unsigned ZERO = 0;` you can use `x < ZERO` instead. No warnings, and the ZERO will likely be optimized away.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY, tried with clang++. No such luck. But I was so hopeful. :)
Can disable/enable the warning around comparison line, [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/disabling-clang-compiler-warnings/).
`#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wtautological-compare"`