# gcc gives no warning for comparing unsigned integer < 0 even with Wextra enabled

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning, gcc7

Take the following code

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
T f(T x, unsigned y) {
    if (y < 0) return x;
    return static_cast<T>(0);
}

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int a = f(2, 3);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

where function `f` clearly always returns 0. Compiling it with `g++-7.2.0 -Wall -Wextra` gives no hint about pointless comparison. However, clang warns us nicely:

```
a.cpp:7:11: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
    if (y < 0) return x;
        ~ ^ ~
1 warning generated.
```

Why is this so (I presume templates are the root of the problem) and can `gcc` be forced to output the warning in this case?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. `gcc` normally implements this warning, as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598556/g-warning-comparison-of-unsigned-expression-0-is-always-false

Comment: gcc [normally catches these types of issues using -Wconversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22047204/1708801) but it looks like it breaks for templates ... seems like a bug, please [file a bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/)

Comment: Yeah, it works on simpler examples, I just wanted to check if there is some trick involving templates, before filing a stupid bug report. Thanks!

Comment: Filed as [bug82924](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82924).

Answer (score 1):

This is a regression bug in some versions of GCC (including 8.x and 9.x - which are still the default compilers on many distributions at the time of writing).

The bug was tracked [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82521) (@jureslak file it again, but that was marked as dupe) and has been resolved. [See the warning with GCC 10.1](https://godbolt.org/z/8SeCRF) (Godbolt).